# While loop pagination inside foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, pagination

I am displaying exact match results from the database with TMDB similar movies API.

```
$imdbid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['movie']);

$similarapiurl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/{$imdbid}/similar?api_key=cfe422613b250f702980a3bbf9e90716";

$similarmovies = json_decode(file_get_contents($similarapiurl), true);

$i=0;

foreach ($similarmovies['results'] AS $similarmovie) { 

    $movietitle = $similarmovie['original_title'];
    $movieyear = substr($similarmovie['release_date'], 0, 4);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE EngTitle COLLATE utf8_general_ci='".$movietitle."' AND Year LIKE '%".$movieyear."%'";
    $movieresult = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if ($i==10) break;
    if ($movieresult->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $movieresult->fetch_assoc()) {
        $i++;
    ?>
    <div class="movie-card" data-id="<?php echo $row['ImdbID']; ?>">
      <div class="item-card">
        <div class="rating">
          IMDB <span class="score"><?php echo $row['ImdbRating']; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay ov-show">
          <div class="description">
            <?php echo mb_strimwidth($row['Description'], 0, 80, "..."); ?>
          </div>
          <div class="info">
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i> დაწვრილებით
          </div>
          <div class="actions">
            <a href="/similar/<?php echo $row['ImdbID']; ?>" class="like">
              <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> მაჩვენე მსგავსი
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <img src="<?php echo $row['PosterURL']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row['EngTitle']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="subtitle">
        <h6><?php echo $row['GeoTitle']; ?></h6>
        <span class="meta"><?php echo $row['EngTitle']; ?> / <?php echo $row['Year']; ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        } $movieresult->free();
    }
    }
    }
```

As you can see from code I'm running `foreach` loop on the array and inside that `while` loop to get results from the database. I'm breaking foreach loop on 10th run so it only displays first 10 results.

Now I want to paginate. I want to run the loop, get all `$movietitle` and display first 10, rest to be rendered but hidden and after button or link click to be shown. So it will look like pagination, but will be instant, like tabbed content.

I tried `array_slice()` but it was not slicing array correctly. How can I do that and should I find a solution in JavaScript or in PHP?

Comment: I think this calls for javascript seeing as how you want to instantly display the results. If you use php, you'll have to wait for a page reload.

Comment: @dgig if there is a PHP solution I would like to hear it :)

Comment: There's no PHP solution for this. PHP is a backend language and what you want is frontend functionality. Basicly all you have to do is retrieve all the results and show / hide them with Javascript

Comment: I mean, you could do php but it would be slow. Just add a "page" GET variable and use the MySQL `LIMIT` clause instead of trying to grab everything and slice the array.